# Flutter container wave border

Tags: flutter, dart, shapes, wave

Any Idea how we can design this with dart?

I've tried using using stacks and containers but I'm not getting a so good result?

Or any package for this?

[image]

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers may help you

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312 check all the examples

Answer (score 1):

**Two package**

1. dotted_line: ^3.1.0
2. dotted_border: ^2.0.0+2

Answer (score 1):

You may try customised svg design.
But if you want to customised flutter view you can use custom paint from third party customisable tools like **[Flutter Shape Maker](https://shapemaker.web.app/#/)**. Web link: https://fluttershapemaker.com/

For better example you can view this [video](https://vimeo.com/467083148?embedded=true&source=video_title&owner=124864662)

Answer (score 0):

I heard about *Flutter* **QUADRATIC BEZIER** and learnt.

Looks a bit complicated first..., but It's worth learning to use it.

You really can do a bunch of thing with it.

And I didn't have to use any package, It did the job for me.

```
CustomPaint(
    size: Size(screenWidth * 0.9, 500),
    painter: DemoPainter(color: Colors.white),
    ),
```

```
class DemoPainter extends CustomPainter {
  const DemoPainter({
    Key? key,
    required this.color,
  });
  // : super(key: key);
  final Color color;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    double sw = size.width;
    double sh = size.height;
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    Path path = Path()..moveTo(sw * 0.05, sh);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, sh, 0, sh * 0.95);
    path.lineTo(0, sh * 0.05);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, sw * 0.05, 0);

    path.lineTo(sw * 0.25, 0);

    //----------------------------------------------------------------

    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.30, 0, size.width * 0.35, 20);

    // path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.60, 20),
    //     radius: Radius.circular(10), clockwise: false);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.50, 80, size.width * 0.65, 20);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.70, 0, size.width * 0.75, 0);

//----------------------------------------------------------------
    path.lineTo(sw * 0.95, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(sw, 0, sw, sh * 0.05);
    path.lineTo(sw, sh * 0.95);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(sw, sh, sw * 0.95, sh);

    canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.grey, 5, true);

    
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```